# Pandas df.apply does not modify DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I am just starting pandas so please forgive if this is something stupid.

I am trying to apply a function to a column but its not working and i don't see any errors also.

```
 capitalizer = lambda x: x.upper()
    for df in pd.read_csv(downloaded_file, chunksize=2, compression='gzip', low_memory=False):
        df['level1'].apply(capitalizer)
        print df
        exit(1)
```

This print shows the `level1` column values same as the original csv not doing `upper`. Am i missing something here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`apply` is not an *inplace* function - it does not modify values in the original object, so you need to assign it back:

```
df['level1'] = df['level1'].apply(capitalizer)
```

---

Alternatively, you can use `str.upper`, it should be much faster.

```
df['level1'] = df['level1'].str.upper()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df['level1'] = map(lambda x: x.upper(), df['level1'])
```

you can use above code to make your column uppercase